# How to do Java web development without a local environment

Tags: java

I started a new job recently. I've been a Java & XML web developer for two years. The new place I'm at has several large web applications, but none of them deploy to my local JBOSS server because some genius decided to create a Java Project instead of a Dynamic Web Project. I tried following the steps to convert the project but that creates a bunch of errors which I cannot resolve.

The people I work with are all consultants and never give me a straight answer on how I can develop/test my changes locally.

Has anyone had to program in a similar situation? If so... got any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on projects like that, but with Tomcat as the server instead of JBoss.  I develop in Eclipse using a normal Java project, and I follow these steps:

1. Run an Ant script to build the project into a new WAR in a temp workspace directory.
2. Use an Eclipse plugin to stop the local test server.
3. Run an Ant script to copy the WAR to the proper directory for Tomcat to pick it up and deploy it.
4. Use an Eclipse plugin to start the local test server.

Tomcat's fast and the project isn't huge, so this whole process takes 12-15 seconds.  With JBoss being a full enterprise app server, I'd think it might take more time.